# Can't get write permission on external hard drive when exporting from Lightroom

Tags: hard-drive, photos, external-disk, permission

A few days ago I bought a new 2018 MacBook Pro which is running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I have been a Windows user till then.

After I edited my photos on the new Mac in Lightroom, I plugged in my external drive (WD My Passport) and I went on to export them. In Lightroom I got an error that said I can't export on that drive since it has only read privileges or something like that. So I went on to googling the issue and found out that I have to change the permission. I tried that but the next obstacle was that the **Apply to enclosed items** option is greyed out.

I googled that problem but i haven't found a solution so far. Is this problem happening because I have to reformat my external drive on something other that NTFS? Or is there a setting i missed? Or something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS doesn't natively contain the software (drive) to write onto a disk formatted with NTFS (but it can read NTFS formatted drives fine). That's what the error is implying that only read privileges are available.

A drive formatted with NTFS can be written to by installing NTFS driver software in macOS. For writing to external disks made by WD, you will need to install a proprietary NTFS driver for macOS provided by the disk manufacturer called Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac.

You can follow the instructions in this support article on WD website, [How to Install the Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=20717#subject2), to install the software and gain the ability to write files to the disk.

Comment: is there a format that i can format the disk so i dont have to install this driver?

Comment: You can format the drive with HFS/HFS+ which is Apple's proprietary format. However, this will leave you with the similar problem in Windows where you will require a drive to read/write. You can use HFS+ if you plan to use the disk only with a Mac.

Comment: @weinde You can format the drive in exFAT whch is readable and writeable by Windows and macOS (and Linux)

Answer (score 1):

this issue started for me when I updated to 10.13.6 from 10.13.4. It seems like the current/latest version of Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac is not supported for Macos 10.13.6. Please let me know if anyone finds a workaround or a solution to this problem.